# How to escape html tag from src

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using img tag and getting image dynamically but output is coming with html tag.

```
 <img src="<?php  echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), "medium", true);?>"/>
```

Output is coming with

```
"/>
```

Comment: share what you get `<div><?php  echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), "medium", true);?></div>` ?

Comment: user2486@Bro out put is coming with this  "/> my out put is my desire output .but its coming with this html tag

Comment: try with `htmlspecialchars` like `<div><?php echo htmlspecialchars(wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), "medium", true));?></div>`

Comment: use `'medium'` instead of `"medium"`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `wp_get_attachment_image function` returns an `img tag` not an url so you just need to `echo` it.

Comment: saeed yahyapour@I have done this ,Thanks for your support.I have posted my answere.please see this

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function.

**wp_get_attachment_image** provides the whole image tag with html.

Reference : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/

What you are looking for is **wp_get_attachment_image_src**

Reference :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/

**Try this code:**

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), "medium", true ); ?>" />
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: shazyriver@I have  Answered my question

Answer (score 0):

Well Thanks Every one .I have solution

```
<?php $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "size" );?>

<img src="<?php echo $thumbnail[0];?>">
```